# Multi-Criteria Optimization with Reinforcement Learning

Tags: machine-learning, power-management, reinforcement-learning

I am working on the power management of a system. The objectives that I am looking to minimize are power consumption and average latency. I have a single objective function having the linearly weighted sum of both the objectives:

```
C=w.P_avg+(1-w).L_avg,      where w belongs to (0,1)
```

I am using Q-learning to find a pareto-optimal trade-off curve by varying the weight w and setting different preference to power consumption and average latency. I do obtain a pareto-optimal curve. My objective, now, is to provide a constraint (e.g., average latency L_avg) and thus tuning/finding the value of w to meet the given criteria. Mine is an online algorithm, so the tuning of w should take place in an online fashion.

Could I be provided any hint or suggestions in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a multiple-objective Reinforcement Learning branch in the community.

The idear is to [1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.34.5216):

> assign a family of agents to each objective. The solutions obtained by the agents in one family are compared with the solutions obtained by the agents from the rest of the families. A negotiation mechanism is used to find compromise solutions satisfying all the objectives.

Also there a paper that might be interest to you:

**Multi-objective optimization by reinforcement learning for power system dispatch and voltage stability**.

I did not find a public url for it though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But the recommended papers/methods with multi-agent RL are for off-policy learning or episodic  tasks. In my case, I have an online learning problem.